# What is difference between 'docker ps -all' and 'docker ps -a'?

Tags: docker

The command 'docker ps -all' gives me all the created containers but 'docker ps -a' also supposed to give me same results but somehow it returns me only 1 or sometimes 2 latest entries of containers.

Can someone please explain me? I am new to docker. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: They are indeed aliases (at least in the version I'm using) `-a, --all             Show all containers (default shows just running)`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Your statement is true, but OP uses `-all` not `--all`. `docker ps -all` is the same as `docker ps -al`. A look at docker ps --help reveals:`-a, --all Show all containers (default shows just running)... -l, --latest Show the latest created container (includes all states)`

Comment: @Turing85: ah, eagle eye!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between `docker ps -a` (which is identical to `docker ps --all`) and `docker ps -all`.

We can see the difference by looking at [the documentation of `docker ps`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/):

```
Options
Name, shorthand     Default     Description
--all , -a                      Show all containers (default shows just running)
--filter , -f                   Filter output based on conditions provided
--format                        Pretty-print containers using a Go template
--last , -n         -1          Show n last created containers (includes all states)
--latest ,  -l                  Show the latest created container (includes all states)
--no-trunc                      Don't truncate output
--quiet , -q                    Only display container IDs
--size , -s                     Display total file sizes
```

As we can see: `docker ps -a` and `docker ps --all` are identical.

Meanwhile, `docker ps -all` uses the shorthand form and is identical to `docker ps -al`. This command will only show the most recently created container.

Comment: Understood. I think I have to start using double hyphen instead of single one.
Thanks @Turing85

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [in the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/) `-a` is just short for `--all`, they serve the same purpose.

Comment: You may want to read the question more carefully. OP uses `-all` not `--all`.

Comment: Yeah I think he missed a hyphen, anyway, good catch, +1 to your answer (as soon as I can as I am maxed out today :P)

Comment: Speculative answers are discouraged. We should rather ask for clarification in the comments. And your guess is most probably wrong since the behaviour described pretty much fits the expectation of executing `docker ps -all`.

Comment: Yeah, but I think it's not a very dangerous assumptions as `-all` most probably is miss typed as anyone who actually intended `-al` would just write it without the redundant `l` at the end and not like `-all`. Also, one other reason why I assumed he miswrote is because he clearly stated he is a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

docker ps -a and docker ps --all are same commands but if you use docker ps -all command it will return just last created container. docker ps -all is same as docker ps -al.